# Excel auto-formating text to 12-hour format

Tags: excel, formatting, autoformatting

I have an Excel file that is doing something very weird.

In a cell I should have the value "1.01.02" but my Excel is understanding that this value is "1:01:02 AM".

I have tried to change the format already but it doesn't work. The values that should be in this format "1.01.02" when converted to text it gives me some weird number.

I have no idea what to do. Really need your help!

Thank you so much

Comment: Format the cells to Text before entering the data, or prepend the values with `'`

Answer (score 0):

Is "1.01.02" intended as a time value? If not you should format the cell as text before you input the value. An alternate way would be adding an apostrophe before the value i.e. '1.01.02, this way Excel takes it as literal text.

If it is intended as a time value then I suggest you use a custom format with the form h.mm.ss

Answer (score 0):

If you have the original data do this:

1. Create a blank column and pre-format as text
2. Copy-paste as values from the original data to the new column.

If you do not have the original data do this:

1. Copy-paste the data from Excel to Word or other text editor
2. Cleanup the text (find replace : with . and remove the AM/PM) in the text editor
3. Delete the incorrect column in the spreadsheet
4. Create a new column and set the formatting to text.
5. Copy-paste the fixed data from the text editor into Excel.

Edit: I should add that this is if you have a lot of data to correct.  If it is a few fields just add ' to the front of the value in the formula bar.